# Как открывать файлы с неизвестным названием, но определенного расширения?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как открывать файлы с неизвестным названием, но определенного расширения (например, .dat) и работать с ним, а также со всеми файлами данного расширения в определенной папке.

Comment: @romaaa32 а как ваш вопрос относится к php и к программированию вообще?

Comment: прямо относится

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если говорить о  php, если мы желаем получить все фалы из директории с расширением .dat,
то:

```
 $arrDir = scandir('/home/'); # где /home/ это путь к папке
 foreach($arrDir as $element) { #Перебираем файлы
  if(preg_match('/.dat/',$element)) { 
   //а тут что-то делаем с конкретным файлом
  }
 }
```

(код не проверен на работоспособность).

Comment: @Flur

    foreach (new \DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item) {
        if ($item->getExtension() !== 'dat') {
            continue;
        }
        // real processing
    }

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: есть сильно лучше функция - [glob](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php). С ней уже не нужно условие.

К тому же в приведенном выше коде есть ошибка. к примеру, можно создать файл с именем вида `.dat.avi.txt` (не спрашивайте зачем). Этот файл как бы текстовый, то код выше думает не так:)

Comment: @KoVadim согласен у вас лучше, но сложнее. @Etki извратиться можно, но если знаеш про это ограничение то ничего страшного ибо встречаеться редко.

Comment: @Flur, 

>>у вас лучше, но сложнее

Не гоните. У него и лучше, и проще.

Comment: Опробовал все представленные методы. Спасибо разобрался со всеми.